# How to align all content to the right of the page and limit how far the border on my text goes?

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the image below, I have some text which the code and css for is below:

[image]

```html
<style>
  .top {
    text-align: right;
  }
</style>
<h1 style="align-content:center">Grading Station</h1>
<div class="top">
  <dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2" style="border: 1px solid black;display:inline-block">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OutturnReferenceNo)
            </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10" style="border: 1px solid black;">
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OutturnReferenceNo)
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

How can I get the border around the "H2311171" to only go around the text and not around the empty space, and have the label "Outturn Reference No" directly to the left of my text?

Comment: Try to ask your questions with a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet you used [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) which is actually built with CSS's flex feature. In your example, it would be the easiest to just directly use [Bootstrap's flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/) ([more info about CSS flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)):

```css
.top {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    Text
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

I've changed your elements to DIVs for readability.